# Free merge tools

Tags: merge

I need free merge tool, in order to compare differences in 2 directories. I used Beyond Compare and Araxis Merge, but this tools are not free. Maybe you can recommend some other? I tried WinMerge, but it is not comfortable to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winmerge is something that i use and i find it very comfortable. Why not try examdiff?

Answer (score 3):

[KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) is good, open source (GPL), and works across many platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the diff/merge tool that comes with perforce. You can select it in the client installer. Perforce is free to use for max two database users, so you should be fine with none. :)

Comment: You can use `p4merge` without needing to use a perforce database so the database user restriction is irrelevant if you just want to use their merge tool for free.

Answer (score 0):

I use [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) pretty much every day

Answer (score 0):

[Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) is simply the best merge tool I've ever used. Sadly I don't think there is a Windows version. It can compare directories.

If you use SVN, Tortoise SVN comes with a merge tool.

Comment: Tortoise SVN can compare only the same directory. I would use it, but it compares changes made to directory with the state of directory, when it was last updated.

Comment: Meld is available for Windows: http://meldmerge.org/

Answer (score 0):

For a long time I stubbornly refused to pay for a merge tool and searched high and low for a free merge tool that I liked, but I found that all free merge tools I tried had their quirks.

In the end I got a trial copy of Beyond Compare and found that I liked using it a lot more than the free tools I'd tried so far.  If you're struggling to find a free compare tool that you can work with then don't discount commercial tools - Beyond Compare is very reasonably priced and I use compare tools all the time.  For me the cost was worth it.